# How to initialize a tensor using a multiplication of another two tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering if that is possible I can initialize a 2D tensor W from the value of another two tensor A and B (A and B come from checkpoint).
The init weight of W equals tf.matmul(A, B). After the initialization, W has nothing to do with A/B and the training can update the weights in W and A/B can be ignored from graph.

Comment: Wouldn't `w = tf.Variable(tf.linalg.matmul(A,B))` work? Tested this with 2 `tf.constant` tensors and it worked. (Didn't check with checkpoints though)